# rstudioapi::executeCommand("executeSetupChunk") does not execute setup-chunk

Tags: r, rstudio

## `executeSetupChunk`does not work

When working interactively in an Rmd-document in Rstudio I would assume that this line:

`rstudioapi::executeCommand("executeSetupChunk")`

...would execute the setup-chunk, so that the dataset `diamonds` from `ggplot2` would be available in the global environment. But that's not the case.

Example of Rmd:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
date: "2023-05-02"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup}

library(ggplot2)

```


```{r}

rstudioapi::executeCommand("executeSetupChunk")

diamonds

```
````

After running this line:

```
rstudioapi::executeCommand("executeSetupChunk")
```

...`diamonds` is still not available:

```
> diamonds
Error: object 'diamonds' not found
```

Have I misunderstood the purpose or proper use of `executeSetupChunk`?